# UIImageView changing size unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have `UITableView` with cells that have images on it. Im using storyboard, and connect `UIImageView` as outlet and name it `imageView`. Images what I get come with different size (i download it through URL). But when table shows up sometimes image shown in incorrect size (it suppose to be square with 66x66 width and height, but in many cases square is bigger, or it actually have more width then height).

Obviously i want that borders of my `UIImageView` be stable. There is my code for cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *labelText = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    labelText.text = [[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"imageFirst"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dashie.png" ]completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){

        UIImage *resizedImage = [image resizedImageWithBounds:CGSizeMake(66, 66)];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


        cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.bounds.size.width /2.0f;
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 82, 0, 0);

       cell.imageView.image = resizedImage ;


    }];




    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

return cell;
}
```

Please explain me whats going on and how to fix that, any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new imageView and set the image. I would recommend you make  subclass of uitablviewCell and add the imageView as outlet view

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        UILabel *labelText = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
        labelText.text = [[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

        if (cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
        imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [cell addSubview:imgView];
        imgView.tag = 7;
        }

       UIImageView *img = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:7];
       UIImage *resizedImage = [image resizedImageWithBounds:CGSizeMake(66, 66)];
       img.imqge = resizedImage
```

Comment: Why you create 2 instance of UIImageView?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban there is only one instance of UIImageView, *img is a reference to the imageView that was created and added to cell, returned by the tag, when the cell is reused.

Answer (score 1):

You are using standard UITableViewCell class and try to change its imageView property. Not your cell, that you created on Storyboard.

You should look through this tutorial [Storyboards Tutorial in iOS 7: Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1).
Your are interested in part:

1. **Designing Your Own Prototype Cells**
2. **Using a Subclass for the Cell**

I'll recommend use subclass of UITableViewCell issue.